# Handling Streams Termination with Akka Streams Kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I'm using the Akka Streams Kafka library to interact with Kafka broker. I have the following stream definition with an UnBounded buffer:

```
  def producerStream[T: MessageType](producerProperties: Map[String, String]) = {
    val streamSource = source[T](producerProperties)
    val streamFlow = flow[T](producerProperties)
    val streamSink = sink(producerProperties)
    streamSource.via(streamFlow).to(streamSink).run()
  }
```

I call the producerStream from within an Actor instance. I have a message of type:

```
case class InitiateStream[T](publisher: ActorRef, anyMessage: T)
```

In my Actor, I have the following Receive block:

```
  override def receive: Receive = super.receive orElse {
    case StartProducerStream(publisherActor, DefaultMessage) =>
      producerStream[DefaultMessage](cfg.producerProps)
      // context.become(active)

    case other => println(s"SHIT !! Got unknown message: $other")
  }
```

The publisherActor will eventually get the messages that are supposed to be pushed to the respective Kafka topic.

Now my question is, do I have to bother about closing the producerStream?

I was thinking about doing a context.become(active(producerStream)) as soon as I start the stream and in the active method, I will handle the stream termination based on a DestroyStream message. Is this needed? What do you guys think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Akka Kafka consumer, the source emits events indefinitely as far as events are available in the topic. Why do you need to close the producer?

I´ll suggest to call the following to start your source:

```
def producerSource[T: MessageType](producerProperties: Map[String, String]) = {
    val streamSource = source[T](producerProperties)
    val streamFlow = flow[T](producerProperties)
    val streamSink = sink(producerProperties)
    streamSource.via(streamFlow)
  }

def startStream[A](source: Source[A, NotUsed])(
  implicit am: ActorMaterializer): (UniqueKillSwitch, Future[Done]) = {
   source
   .viaMat(KillSwitches.single)(Keep.right)
   .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.both)
   .run
}

var streamHandler : Option[UniqueKillSwitch] = None

  override def receive: Receive = super.receive orElse {
    case StartProducerStream(publisherActor, DefaultMessage) =>
      streamHandler = Some(producerStream[DefaultMessage](cfg.producerProps))
      context.become(active)

    case other => println(s"SHIT !! Got unknown message: $other")
  }
```

and for the active behavior:

```
   val active: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = 
     case DestroyStream => 
        if(streamHandler.isDefined)
            streamHandler.shutdown
```

Comment: I would prefer to avoid using var of any sorts in my Actor. That was the reason why I wanted to context become! We are talking about an infinite producer stream not a consumer stream!

Comment: Don't I need to shut down the Producer stream when my application is shutting down? Or I don't have to care about it?

Comment: Maybe you should, although it would depend if you must care about what are the latest consumed message and to persist the latest offset, or if you don´t care about duplicated messages...